# PHP Mysql: Select column and add last current value with a new one

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert

i am trying to add the last value from a specific column in mysql with a new value.

$result return me nothing.

ex: last value=100 , value5=50, new value should be 150.

```
        // Read values into table.
        $sql = "SELECT specific_column FROM data WHERE id=LAST_INSERT_ID()";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        // Insert values into table.
        $sql = "INSERT INTO data (column1, column2, column3, column4, specific_colum)
        VALUES ($value1, $value2, $value3, $value4, $result+$value5 )";
```

Answer (score 1):

`$result`  is `mysqli` object .you can not get column value directly.You need to fetch row values first like this..

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$last_value = $row['specific_column'];
$update_value = $last_value+$value5;//now update $update_value in database
```

> The `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` function fetches a result row as an associative array.

Comment: You have to try this after inserting.Otherwise last_insert_id() will be NULL.And NULL+something is always NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MysQLi?

Have you tried a :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ....";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Or:

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Then use **$last_id** as you wish

Answer (score 0):

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` does not return any values which you instered in row.but it only return ROW ID which you instered or updated in form of 0,1,2 etc or
Returns the value generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous INSERT or UPDATE statement.

**uses:-**

Use this function after you have performed an INSERT statement into a table that contains an AUTO_INCREMENT field, or have used INSERT or UPDATE to set a column value with LAST_INSERT_ID(expr).

[For more reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-insert-id.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here, LAST_INSERT_ID will not return anything

> As  LAST_INSERT_ID() returns a BIGINT UNSIGNED (64-bit) value
>   representing the first automatically generated value successfully
>   **inserted for an AUTO_INCREMENT column as a result of the most recently executed INSERT statement**. The value of LAST_INSERT_ID()
>   remains unchanged if no rows are successfully inserted.

So, in place of LAST_INSERT_ID you can use `MAX`

```
$sql = "SELECT specific_column FROM data WHERE id= (select MAX(id) from data)";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just  **need to update `specific_column` value with some N number** then try this

```
UPDATE data SET
    specific_column  = @specific_column  := specific_column + $value5
WHERE ..... ;
```

---

> So `$value5 =50` then `specific_column`  will be 100+50

Comment: @Limehaze check thiis

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT specific_column FROM data WHERE id= (select MAX(id) from data)";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$sql = "INSERT INTO data (column1, column2, column3, column4, specific_colum)
        VALUES ($value1, $value2, $value3, $value4, $row['specific_colum']+$value5 )";
```

Comment: i am trying your solution right now, on line 4, i get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: please add '".$value1."' instead of $value1